# automatic sizing by screen calculations

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a picture in the center of my cell, I added a leading and a trailing to center this, it works in a lot of devices but when I try to display this on the iPhone 4 the screen is too small so the length of the leading and trailing are too longs so the picture is compressed and we could not see the image.

[image]

So I want to do calculations like leading = screen_width/3 and trailing = screen_width/3

It is possible and it is a good solution ? How to do this or here is an better way ?

Comment: I don't think that is a good solution. Try doing it with auto layout. That will be far easier. If you want to centralize your image view, then you should try using the "Center horizontally Option". I gave a full solution. You may wanna try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is such requirement that you want to show **View A** in centre of **View B**, I recommend the following constraints:

```
- View A : Equal Width to superview (i.e. View B), with multiplier. (In your case 1/3 = 0.33).
- View B : Equal Height to superview (i.e. View A), with multiplier. (In your case 1/3 = 0.33).
- View A Center Vertically to superview (i.e. View B).
- View A Center Horizontally to superview (i.e. View B).
```

Comment: How do you implement the multiplier ?

Comment: In the Image you posted in your question you can see Multiplier  property.

Comment: Ohh okay, I never used this, I'm gonna look at the useful

Answer (score 0):

If the leading will be `w / 3` and trailing is the same. So the image width itself is `w / 3` as well. So set Width constraint to be `width = superview.width / 3`. Then add another constraint to center it horizontally

Comment: xCode says: No '*' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSLayoutConstraint!'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to centralize your image, you can do it through auto layout and that should work for all the devices. This is the approach I would take-

First take an image view inside your table view cell and with cursor centralize it.

Now-
Step 1: control drag from the image view to you table view's content view.

[image]

and select "Center horizontally" and "Center vertically option".

[image]

At this point, you may see some red or yellow line but avoid that. We are going to deal with that now.

Step 2:
Pin the top and botton to the content view. Here I assumed your image height is same as your cell height but that can change according to your requirement.

So, pin to the content view like -

[image]

Now you are just left with your image's width. In my case I assumed it is going to be same as the height , so I just had to control drag to itself and select "Aspect Ration" like-

[image]

This is you final constrains

[image]

That should work fine. If your image view's width is not same as your its height then you can you "Equal Width" property with respect to the cell's content view and tell it how you like your width to be.

You DO NOT use trailing or leading space constraints when you are centralize an object inside another.

Comment: Okay sure I can center horizontally by doing this, but the image size is not by the cell height, I want to specify a size and automatically resize it by changing device.

Comment: Then you should also calculate that using proportionality. Use the "Equal Height" constrain with respect to the cell's content view.